# Measuring area of raster within polygons using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, vector-layer, land-classification

I am trying to use QGIS3.10 to analyze the area of forest within regions. It looks like this
[image]

where the polygons belongs to WFS layer and Rasters belongs to WMS layer.
The legends fo Raster suggests that the raster contains different catagories, looks like this
[image]

I would like to find the percentage of green areas in polygons based on percentage coverage info provided in Raster. I have tried converting raster to polygons (with no polygons outcome), raster zonal analysis (with error message) and Extract layer content (no desired outcome).

Can anyone suggest me a way to extract the data from it?

I have knowledge in Python, but I have no idea on how to handle this kind of data.

Dataset used in this case:

http://geo.stat.fi/geoserver/postialue/wfs 
-> Paavo-postinumeroalueet 2019
https://image.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/services/GioLandPublic/HRL_TreeCoverDensity_2015/MapServer/WMSServer 
-> Tree Cover Density 2015

Comment: I think that you need an own copy of the data. About the WFS layer, exporting it as a vector layer should work. About to extract the data of the WMS layer, it can be done with a GetMap request mehod. I wrote an answer to get a WMS raster dataset with GRASS GIS to the following question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305663/save-wms-layer-to-tiff-raster/305782